# How to create navigation view open on condition?

Tags: java, android

First of all, I have two navigation view for both sides in android as shown in this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z46jN.jpg). Left side for user who signup as parents meanwhile the right side for the user who signup as a tuition provider. For example, if User A signs up as a parent, so he/she can only open the left side navigation ONLY. I have made some studies, mostly using radio button/radio group. Unfortunately, I have to use the spinner, what coding should I write to ensure the navigation view can be opened for certain users. For your information, I have 3 activity.

1) **User.Java** wherein coding, I have coding initialize, constructor and getter.

2) RegistrationActivity.Java where I put all the spinner coding.

```
//USER TYPE SPINNER
    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    categories.add(0, "Choose Category");
    categories.add("Parents");
    categories.add("Tuition Provider");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    RegisterUserType.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    RegisterUserType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            if(position==0)
            {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Item Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),parent.getItemAtPosition(position) +" Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

3) Home.Java where I put all my navigation view coding.

```
menuLeft = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menu_left);
    menuRight = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menu_right);

    parentsNavigation = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    tuitionProviderNavigation = findViewById(R.id.nav_view2);

    menuLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
            {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }

            else
            {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        }
    });

    menuRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END))
            {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
            }

            else
            {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
            }
        }
    });

    parentsNavigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
        {
            UserMenuSelector(item);
            return false;
        }
    });

    tuitionProviderNavigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
        {
            UserMenuSelector(item);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I can not paste all my coding here because it is too long but I can email you to better understand my XML layout.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is lock the drawer that you want to Disable and unlock again if you want to Enable it

use `drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode();`

in your case below code will close your one drawer that have gravity start

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, GravityCompat.START);
```

and when you want to unlock again then simply

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED, GravityCompat.START);
```

Remember one more thing

> `drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode()` allows the application to restrict the user's ability to open or close the given drawer (cannot open via sliding) but DrawerLayout will still respond to calls to openDrawer(), closeDrawer()

so in your case you also consider disabling the ImageView click because they have these methods

**In Your Case**

when user will click on a spinner item you check `if(position==1)`
if this condition true you know it's a parent

so do this in your Home.Java

do this

```
    if(parent==true){

//this will disable right drawer

drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, GravityCompat.END);

//and this will enable left drawer
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED, GravityCompat.START);

//and also do to disable right ImageView
menuRight.setEnabled(false); 

//and also do to enable left ImageView
menuLeft.setEnabled(true);}
```

now for tuition provider do same but this time enable right and disable left,
also same for menu button.

Comment: How to unlock and lock it? What I want is, if the user is a parents, ONLY left navigation view can be open.

Comment: so if user is parents then simply lock right navigation so they can only open left

Comment: wait i'll rewrite your code and update my answer so you can understand better

Comment: No it's just a hint... You can declare a variable and store is clicked position is parent or not... It's like a boolean... True and false

Comment: where should I declare the variable? Inside the same Activity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179145/discussion-between-user10284194-and-ashwini-violet).

Comment: The drawerLayout for the left side can't work if the user is a tuition provier...

Comment: If you will implement my answer then you will get desired solution... I tested this myself... All you have to do is make a condition..

Comment: if(RegistrationActivity.tuitionProviderType.equals("Tuition Provider"))
        {
            drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, GravityCompat.END);
            drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED, GravityCompat.START);
            menuRight.setEnabled(true);
            menuLeft.setEnabled(false);
        }

Comment: this one for parent...please discussion in chat